# WebSocket Error: Network Error 12038 - Invalid certificate hostname

Tags: javascript, ssl, https, websocket, certificate

I have an issue doing an https server in javascript with a self-signed certificate. It works on Chrome but i don't get why it doesn't on IE (i've already add the certificate on trusted certificate list, yet i still get this error).

I'm pretty sure my code is right but i can't point out where is the problem.

Does anyone have a clue ?

Thanks.

---

***EDIT***: Here is the creation of the WebSocketServer :

```
var options = {
key: fs.readFileSync('sslcert/key.pem', 'utf8'),
cert: fs.readFileSync('sslcert/cert.pem', 'utf8'),
port : '8443'
}
var httpServer = https.createServer(options, app);
```

Then i add the listener on the port 8443 :

```
httpServer.listen(options.port, function() {
myDate = new Date();
today = myDate.getDate().toString()+(myDate.getMonth() + 1).toString()+myDate.getFullYear().toString();
userName = process.env['USERPROFILE'].split(path.sep)[2];
fs.appendFile('./log/GRCWS_'+os.hostname()+'_'+userName+'_'+today+'.log','Le serveur écoute sur le port ' + config.port+'\n', function(err) {if(err){return console.log(err);} console.log("Log enregistré");});    
});
```

I'm only trying to connect to the server with :

```
var connection = new WebSocket('wss://localhost:8443');
```

Then I got the error : "WebSocket Error: Network Error 12038, The host name in the certificate is invalid or does not match".

Comment: can you add some code? anything you have written so far?

Comment: @TommySM i added the code that should permits the connection, any idea ?

Comment: Use TLS 1.0 (or above) and [Server Name Indication (SNI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). Please post the output of `openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:<port> -tls1 -servername <hostname> | openssl x509 -text -noout`. Do so by adding it to your question by clicking *Edit* (and don't post it as a comment). Otherwise, we can't reproduce it and there's not enough information to help troubleshoot it.